# Data export form occasionally freezes during/after file opens

Tags: .net, vb.net, ado.net

I have data logging software that freezes on some machines during/after the export process. During normal use the main form is logging data. If the user wants to export that data to a spread sheet they follow steps to open a new form. This form also holds focus until the form is closed. The new form has options to select which set of data to be exported. Upon selecting a data set the user hits the export button. The code is long but I'll try to summarize.

```
Private Sub Exoprt_btn_Click(ByVal...)

Dim fs As FileStream = Nothing
Dim fw As StreamWriter = Nothing
Dim ...
```

After this SQL stuff happens to fill out the file. This seems to work correctly because the file always opens and is filled properly.

At the end of the code we have

```
fw.Close()
fs.Close()
fw.Dispose()
fs.Dispose()
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(FileName)
```

At this point, when the code works the spreadsheet opens and the user can save or close as they see fit. After dealing with the new file they can return to the pop-up window, select new data to export or close the window and work with the main form.

But when the software freezes, upon returning to the data logging program the data export form is usually blank or sometimes objects like buttons and labels are partially loaded. The export window still holds focus but the main form is still updating as new data is logged. Trying to close the export window results in a windows not responding dialogue. Restarting the computer reveals that everything in the background was working as intended except the window's features could not be interacted with.

I tried to identify the malicious code by writing in Sleep periods and a text message.

```
fw.Close()
label1.text = "fw.Close()"
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
fs.Close()
label1.text = "fs.Close()"
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
...
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Filename)
label1.text = "Open File"
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
```

The result was that after closing Excel the user only saw "Open File" if the program didn't freeze and "Label1" if it did.

I did some research and ran across some thoughts about threading where this set of code was not being interthreaded properly since the main window is threaded and doing its own thing. I am not sure why some computers run properly and some seem to lock up consistantly.

More experiments:

1) Just opening the Export window can cause the window to freeze while it is logging. Upon opening the export window the program populates a datagridview-like object from SQL.

2) I can use another instance of the logging software to grab data while the original instance is logging. This still causes the main window of the primary instance to lock up.

3) One computer that used to exhibit the symptoms seems to have been excorcised of its demons.

Comment: I ran the code and it just had fw.Close() and then System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Filename) and it still froze and sometimes with a new syptom where it would freeze before opening the Excel file.

Comment: Played around exporting while the data logging was between threads. Was able to export twice before it froze. Thinking of doing some testing next week.

Comment: There isn't enough code here to make a valid attempt.

Comment: Calling Thread.Sleep() does not release control back to the Windows message pump, and so the screen won't update. All you did was set a property in memory. That information won't make it to the screen.

Comment: For the giggles, try these two ideas separately, and report back on whether your app still freezes: (1) Comment out `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Filename)`. (2) Change the file extension of `Filename` to .txt (or whatever) so that `Process.Start` opens it with Notepad instead.

Comment: rskar: Commenting out still causes the window freeze. I have edited the original post, but just to be clear mearly the act of opening and then closing the window (I need to confirm that it wait for the window to close) causes the main form to lose interactivity.

Comment: If your `StreamWriter` is writing to `FileStream`, don't close the `FileStream`. `fw.Close()` will close the file stream. And don't dispose either. That happens when you close. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close.aspx

Comment: Interesting information Mark. I am updating the question to reveal now that I think my problem may lie in the SQL calls. The one computer I have been using to diagnose has become very unstable and I am reformatting and reinstalling the software to see how the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks for all the attention guys! Hopefully something here fixes his problem, Ill award the bounty shortly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.aspx) class.  [This post](http://garylima.blogspot.com/2009/09/backgroundworker.html) should get you started. To update your label1.Text, handle the [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event and pass the progress value through there accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I have been studying but my ability to focus on this problem has been limited.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a class with the export code as a function
2. At the top of the class create/add Delegate Function exportHandler
3. Inside of your form add a handler to the new class with the export function.
4. Create a callbackhandler method to receive the status of the thread performing the export functionality.Have the callbackhandler call an update ui function that checks if the thread is running from the UI or is another thread. (Me.InvokeRequired checks this)
5. Inside of the Form btn click event call the export data Async using the targetHandlerExportData call.

   ```
   Private targetHandlerExportData As ClassName.exportHandler = AddressOf objNewClass.exportData


   Private callbackHandler As AsyncCallback _
                              = AddressOf MyCallbackMethod



   Sub MyCallbackMethod(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
       '*** this code fires at completion of each asynchronous method call
       Try

           Dim retval As Boolean = targetHandlerExportData.EndInvoke(ar)
           If retval = True Then
               Console.Write(retval)
           End If
           UpdateUI("Task complete")

       Catch ex As Exception
           Dim msg As String
           msg = "Error: " & ex.Message
           UpdateUI(msg)

       End Try
   End Sub

   Sub UpdateUI(ByVal statusMessage As String)
       If Me.InvokeRequired Then
           Dim handler As New UpdateUIHandler(AddressOf UpdateUI_Impl)
           Dim args() As Object = {statusMessage}
           Me.BeginInvoke(handler, args)

       Else
           UpdateUI_Impl(statusMessage)
       End If
   End Sub

   Delegate Sub UpdateUIHandler(ByVal statusMessage As String)

   Sub UpdateUI_Impl(ByVal statusMessage As String)
       Me.sbMain.Panels("Status").Text = statusMessage
   End Sub
                     Private Sub Export_btn_Click()
                     Dim result As IAsyncResult = targetHandlerExportData.BeginInvoke(callbackHandler, Nothing)  
                     End Sub
   ```